# Creating RTCVideoframe with CVPixelBuffer

Tags: swift, webrtc, replaykit

Need help in  creating RTCVideoframe

This is the init method for RTCVideoframe
`RTCVideoFrame(buffer: RTCVideoFrameBuffer, rotation: RTCVideoRotation, timeStampNs: Int64)`

I am able to get input buffer as CVPixelBuffer

How can I convert `CVpixelBuffer` to `RTCVideoFrameBuffer`.

Thanks and any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using cmSampleBuffer we received from

`

```
sharedRecorder.startCapture(handler: { (cmSampleBuffer, rpSampleType, error) in
   switch rpSampleType {
  case RPSampleBufferType.video:

{
 let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(cmSampleBuffer)!
 let rtcpixelBuffer = RTCCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
 videoFrame = RTCVideoFrame(buffer: rtcpixelBuffer, rotation: RTCVideoRotation._0, timeStampNs: Int64(timestamp))
}
} )}
```

`